# Radio button value not selected after changing in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue with a radio button after updating its value in controller. It has the Y/N Value, when I load the information it has by default 'N', which is showed, but If I changed to YES, I do some validations and I have to change it back to NO ( I assigned the value in the controller), but in the html is not selected, in fact none of them

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="radioAceptada" ng-model="accepted" value="Y" ng-change="changeValue()">Yes
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="radioAceptada" ng-model="accepted" value="N" ng-change="changeValue()">No
    </label>
  </div>
```

[Plunker with example](https://plnkr.co/edit/nrkErKQdOQC2hEDXhQuV)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is a correct explanation but I think values are updated so fast that angular doesn't have time to update UI. I had a similar problem and solved the issue by adding a 0.5 sec delay.

```
  $scope.changeValue = function() {
    if ($scope.accepted === 'Y') {
      alert("Error");
    $timeout(function() { 
      $scope.accepted = 'N';
    }, 500);
    }
  };
```

Working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BJMV2RNjWSUEjNoCWlf6?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

you must use `ng-value` in view and assign a return function to it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.17"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="radioAceptada0" ng-model="accepted" ng-value='change()' >Yes
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="radioAceptada1" ng-model="accepted" value='N 'ng-value="N" >No
    </label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

your controller :

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.accepted = 'N';
  $scope.change=function(){
    if(validation is apply )
    retrun 'Y';
    else 
    {
      alert("somting you want show");
      return 'N';
    }


      alert("x")
      return 'Y';
  }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry I miss understood your issue. Here is the code, select N even after selecting Y checkbox,

```
  <input type="radio" name="rdly" ng-model="mdly" value="Y" ng-change="changeValue(mdly)">Yes

  <input type="radio" name="rdln" ng-model="mdln" value="N" ng-change="changeValue(mdln)">No
```

You have to specify different names in order to work.

```
$scope.mdln = 'N';
  $scope.changeValue = function() {
    if ($scope.mdly === 'Y') {         
            alert('Change back to N');          
            $scope.mdly = '';   
            $scope.mdln = 'N';
    }       
  };
```

I made changes to my JSfiddle: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/sudi065/uxcfc8mo/)